# How to get date range between two date in Google AppMaker?

Tags: date, calendar, google-app-maker

I have two datebox that capture a start date & end date. I tried do following binding to get the date range between the two date but it return a negative value

`@widget.root.children.DateBox1.value - @widget.root.children.DateBox2.value`

following is my form example

[image]

Comment: You got difference between these two dates in milliseconds. What format do you expect?

Comment: how can I convert them to other format such as days or years instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```javacript
// Binding (option 1 - no datasource)
getValidity(@widget.root.children.StartDate.value, @widget.root.children.EndDate.value);


// Binding (option 2 - with datasource)
getValidity(@datasource.item.StartDate, @datasource.item.EndDate);


// Client script
function getValidity(start, end) {
  if (start && end) {
    var milliseconds = end - start;

   // days: 1000ms * 60s * 60m * 24h
   return milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

   // years: 1000ms * 60s * 60m * 24h * 365d
   // return milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
  }

  return 'n/a';
}
```

Comment: is it directly will bind to datasource?

Comment: It is calculated value. This implementation will not persist it to the database (btw I missed function name in client script in my answer, fixed now).